# Unhandled Error gets thrown in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions, and in one of my projects I have a simple function that looks like the following:

```
exports.responseGiven = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'permission-denied',
        'Must be an user to execute this action'
    );
  }

  const studentPath = data.studentPath;
  const eventPath = data.eventPath;
  const isUpdating = data.isUpdating;

  const studentDoc = await admin.firestore().collection('students').doc('studentPath').get();
  const eventDoc = await studentDoc.ref.collection('entries').doc(eventPath).get();
});
```

I know where the error is through other methods and why it is, I'm using an invalidStudentPath. But the bigger issue is that the error that gets thrown is this for all of my errors in this project:

```
Unhandled error function error(...args) {
   write(entryFromArgs('ERROR', args));
}
```

How can I get the actual error instead of this obscure message? Thanks for any help.

**Update**

---

I have found a workaround for now. Currently I'm wrapping my whole function in a try catch block that looks like this:

```
exports.responseGiven = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('There was an error');
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing that message?

Comment: In the Firebase console. Click the functions in the navbar and the log tab.

Comment: I got the same problem. It throws the same unhandled error even when I have placed everything inside a try catch block

Comment: I could not find any reference to this kind of error anywhere, so it might be a good idea for you to open a case with Google in their [Issue Tracker System](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0) as they might have information on what is causing this and fix it if it is a bug.

Comment: Just created an issue with the link ou gave @ralemos . Now we will see if I get a response

Comment: Just created https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/757, as there there's more chance for the firebase-functions developers to take a look. Specially because it seems to be related to the logger module they introduce in version 3.7.0.

Comment: I have the same issue, the try, catch block does not help in actually giving out a proper error statement, were you able to make the error go away?

Comment: It's fixed in firebase-functions 3.9.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was fixed in [firebase-functions v3.9.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions/v/3.9.1). Alternatively you could downgrade to v3.8.0.

See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/757#issuecomment-673080726

Comment: You must be throwing a `HttpsError` or it will claim the exception is `Unhandled error`

Answer (score 1):

I had a case recently where I forgot to `await` the result of an `async` (`Promise`-returning) function inside the relevant `try` / `catch`, so it escaped to the outer level. In the code I was working on, the logs look similar in the escaped case and `catch` error handler case. It is something that evaded my notice during unit testing because the functions were still triggering the node `assert` rejection hooks with the proper error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error on a new project. Took me a few hours to realize I forgot to initialize firebase admin after I imported it in my functions

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: I am initializing admin in my project. Thanks for your response though, but this is not the issue